# Is there something in this string with a specific meaning in PHP/preg_replace

Tags: php, string, character-encoding

A small part of one of my mail sending objects creates the HTML version of a confirmation email... it's all utf-8 encoded and perfectly happy until I encounter the string that denotes an donation to the RSPCA - for instance `Donation (RSPCA): £1.30`

It's all database driven to retrieve the charity information but I broke it down into simple strings to try and see what was happening, so the insert code looks something like this:

```
$sDonationLabel = preg_replace('/^(\w[^:]+)(\:?)$/u', "$1 ({{THIS_IS_THE_ODDBALL}})$2", $this->_dictionary->read('label_donation_total'));

$sContentInner .= "<tr>\n"
        . "<th colspan=\"3\" align=\"right\"><font face=\"verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif\" size=\"2\" color=\"#404040\">"
        . $sDonationLabel
        . "</font></th>\n"
        . "<td align=\"center\"><font face=\"verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif\" size=\"2\" color=\"#000000\">"
        . $this->_order->getCurrency()->format($this->_order->getDonationValue(), $this->_order->getLocale())
        . "</font></td>\n"
        . "</tr>\n";
```

Replacing that `{{THIS_IS_THE_ODDBALL}}` with various strings gives the following results in the corresponding emails:

**RS**

[image: RS]

**RSP**

[image: RSP]

**RSPC**

[image: RSPC]

**RSPCA**

[image]

**RSPCAB**

[image]

As you can see, when I get the string *'Donation (RSPCA):'* it **seems** to throw the character set out of utf-8 and into latin-8859-1 thus replacing the *£* symbol with 2 "unknown character" symbols (I'm guessing it's a character set juggle from utf-8 to 8859-1 as utf-8 has twice as many bits per character, which would result in that double "unknown" character occurrence). But it seems to revert back to utf-8 at the next text insert block which outputs the *Total: £33.00* table row.

Just to make sure it wasn't something happening within the regular expression, I've also defined the variable `$sDonationLabel` as a string literal, like this:

`$sDonationLabel = 'Donation (RSPCA):';`

Which still results in the corrupted £ symbol.

I know I *could* replace the £ symbol with `&pound;` but I was wondering why that specific string should cause this weird issue - is there something I'm missing, with the character set that means something like `(RSPCA):` has some kind of special meaning that's causing the character set to change ... anything?

Comment: off topic, but please note that the `<font>` tag is deprecated; you should use CSS for font settings.

Comment: on topic: have you done a validity check on your HTML code? Or looked at the generated HTML source code? That might throw some light on the issue. Also, what do the functions `getCurrency()` and `getCurrency()->format()` do? It seems to me that they might be relevant here.

Comment: I know the <font> tag is deprecated - but this is generating an HTML email, and some email clients tend to be somewhat archaic so it's safest to revert right back to HTML 4, no CSS (or at most inline CSS).

Comment: Fair enough. Having said that, can you confirm which browsers/email clients this issue shows up in? Is it common to all, or is it specific to particular clients?

Comment: Oh, the `getCurrency()` stuff is a method of my order object, it simply returns a `Currency` object which implements the `NumberFormatter` class to allow me to format up the currency relevant to the Locale... the same calls are used to generate every £ symbol throughout the HTML document. You've probably got a good point about the email clients though - I've only been testing with Outlook 2010 as that's what gets opened when Antix SMTP imposter catches the emails (this is just running on a dev server atm).